# What happens if the crew do not set a FLT ALT in the cabin pressurization panel and leave it at zero but AUTO is still selected?

Tags: boeing-737, cabin-pressure, acs-pressurization

On the 737NG, will the cabin maintain a lower altitude than the plane or will cabin altitude equal aircraft altitude?
Will there be ANY cabin pressurization or none at all?
When will the HORN sound?

I know this is extremely unlikely to happen but am posing the hypothetical question in order to better understand how the system works.

Answer (score 4):

For the curious, the first two sections explain the *purpose* of manually setting the FLT ALT.
You can **skip** directly to the answer section:

### Intro

There are at least three scenarios to consider, not just one:

1. Left on AUTO on ground with no selection *(your question).*
2. Step climb (from cruise) without updating the selection.
3. Descending before reaching the selection.

Now, let's see how the 737 differs from the typical newer jetliner (the 737NG's *digital* pressurization controller was optional on the 737 Classic):

- In newer planes the pressurization controller is simply fed this data from the FMS (CDU or MCP entry).
- Unlike other jetliners that maintain a cabin altitude with varying differential pressure (DP) for comfort, the 737 maintains a DP based on altitude blocks (consistent structural loads) when the FLT ALT is set. (If you don't have the manual, [b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/pressurisation.htm) covers that part and offers a good system description.)

### Controller logic

Given that, the purpose of setting the FLT ALT on the 737 is maintaining consistent structural loads. The flight manual addresses all scenarios, but for a behind-the-scenes, I'll quote the controller logic from the [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4553474A/en) (side note: 1981 matches the production start of the 737 Classic):

> When the cruise altitude controller senses that the aircraft altitude change is within selected limits [when approx. 1,000 feet below FLT ALT], the system clamps to a scheduled value of cabin altitude [...]
>
> If the aircraft cruise altitude drifts sufficiently to exceed ±500 feet from the altitude at which cruise control was imposed, **the cabin altitude simply unclamps and the cabin climbs or descends at a predetermined rate under the control of central processing unit 54.** [...]
>
> Central processing unit 54 computes the differences between the pressure altitude and the value of H<sub>cruise-clamp</sub> once per minute. If that difference exceeds the predetermined value, **H<sub>cruise-clamp</sub> is assigned the value of the pressure altitude.** [...]

### Direct answer

[image: cabin altitude vs flt alt vs altitude]
<sup>Source: 737 flight manual</sup>

As you see, the FLT ALT value only matters as the plane approaches it (which the controller checks for periodically), else (above/below) the schedule is automatically maintained, so:

The controller will still pressurize the cabin – but not in reference to the DP schedule when cruise is reached, rather in reference to the current pressure altitude.

For an early descent, the controller will engage the off-schedule descent mode – landing altitude being the same as the departure airport altitude that was automatically sensed and set in ground mode – and the crew will be alerted to that. (This is helpful for a diversion/return before reaching the cruise altitude.)

[image]
<sup>*Off-schedule descent* warning, modified from [b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/pressurisation.htm)</sup>

Also, as the illustration shows, in a descent before reaching ~1000 ft below the set FLT ALT, the controller will still reduce the cabin altitude (but not in descent mode).